# Search results jquery output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of search results (json) that I need to output. I used a jquery get method to do so.

But what if there are millions of search results, .. what should I do? What's the best way to handle millions of search results using javascript?

Comment: Use pagination (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination). Only send a subset to the client. For an example, have a look at how Google presents its search results or how Stack Overflow shows the list of questions.